# How to enable speed Boost when Hold Shift

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add a feature when player pressed down Left Shift’ key speed increase and Reset back to normal speed when the Left Shift key Released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Input.GetKey()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) instead of [Input.GetKeyDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) because `Input.GetKeyDown()` only returns true in the one frame you pressed the button.

**Edit 1**

If you want to reset the speed to normal you have to do that in the `else` block like this:

```
void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
  {
    //Increase the speed 
  }
  else
  {
    //Reset to normal speed
  }
}
```

Comment: I have Try this but it doesn't seem to do what i want the speed increased and wont return to normal speed.. I want when player release the speed to return to normal speed

Comment: @suleiman See Edit 1 in my answer, you have to reset the speed in the else block to normalize it.